# Remove position:absolute attribute by adding css

Tags: html, css, dynamic, position, css-position

I have a html element with id="#item" I have a UI event that programaticaly alters the css for "#item" by adding the class ".new" to "#item". Initially I want "#item" to have "position:absolute". However once the class ".new" is added to "#item" the only way I can get the formatting I want in Chrome inspector is to removed position:absolute from the css for "#item". I'd like to accomplish this instead via the css in ".new", however in Chrome inspector my options for changing the position attribute are

```
static
absolute
relative
initial 
inherit
fixed
```

As far as I can tell none of these do the same thing as removing "position:absolute" in Chrome inspector. Can anyone suggest what to put in the css for ".new" to revert to the css default positioning.

Comment: Try leaving the field blank and set important like this: `position: !important;`

Comment: `position: static` is default.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position described. Initial value is static.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ICeweli/1/

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
}

#test {
  position: static;
}
```

Remove one or the other to see the difference.

Answer (score 21):

The [CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position) says that the initial `position` value of an element is `static`.

So in your case if you can't actually remove a declaration then reset it to the "default" which is `static`.

```
#item {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use 'none' as an option.
For my need,

```
.search-bar{
    position: static;
}
```

did the job.